# Number of Days Between a List of Dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table with deals, dates, and volumes in it.  What I need is to calculate the days between the effective dates in a dynamic fashion.  Also complicating this, the first for each deal is in the past but the represents the current deal volume.  So for that line I need to return the number of days from today to the next effective date for that deal.  Furthermore, on the last effective date for each deal, I have to run a subquery to grab the contract end date from another temp table.

Sample of the temp table and the sample return needed:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5r4C.png)

Comment: Why do you want 31 days for the second row?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The desired output makes no sense here at all. You mention some temp table....where is it? The values for days make no sense to me at all.

Comment: I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you know about the LAG() function in SQL Server?   That might be the piece of the puzzle you are missing, since the rest sounds simple.

Comment: 31 is incorrect for the second row.  That value should be 153 which is the difference between 8/1/2019 and 3/1/2019, indicating the deal volume will be 2727 for 153 days.  Sorry for missing that in my proof reading.  I don't know about the LAG() function.  I'll go research that.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding the logic behind days.  I think I understand it, but it's difficult as I believe your sample data is skewed or incorrect.  example - Deal_ID 1479209 in the first table has dates, 11/1, 3/1, 4/1, 6/1.  Second table representing your desired output has dates 11/1, 3/1, 8/1, 9/1...  Where is the dates 8/1 and 9/1 coming from?  is that just a typo?

Comment: Yes Tim I made a mistake in the table.  I reuploaded it and it should make sense now.  I used the lag function and got what it to work for a dataset with only 1 deal in it.  Now I'm altering to make sure it works for multiple deals.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option to explore.

Basically what you're after for each record:

1. Previous record EffectiveDate based on Deal_ID - LAG()
2. Next EffectiveDate after today based on Deal_ID -  Sub query

Then you can evaluate and figure out days based on those values.

Here's a temp table and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Deal
    (
        [Row_ID] INT
      , [Deal_ID] BIGINT
      , [EffectiveDate] DATE
      , [Volume] BIGINT
    );

INSERT INTO #Deal (
                      [Row_ID]
                    , [Deal_ID]
                    , [EffectiveDate]
                    , [Volume]
                  )
VALUES ( 1, 1479209, '2018-11-01', 5203 )
     , ( 2, 1479209, '2019-03-01', 2727 )
     , ( 3, 1479209, '2019-04-01', 1615 )
     , ( 4, 1479209, '2019-06-01', 1325 )
     , ( 5, 1598451, '2018-12-01', 2000 )
     , ( 6, 1598451, '2019-04-01', 4000 )
     , ( 7, 1598451, '2019-08-01', 4000 );
```

Here's an example query using LAG() and sub-query:

```
       SELECT *
                -- LAG here partitioned by the Deal_ID, will return NULL if first record.
            , LAG([dl].[EffectiveDate], 1, NULL) OVER ( PARTITION BY [dl].[Deal_ID]
                                                        ORDER BY [dl].[EffectiveDate]
                                                      ) AS [PreviousRowEffectiveData]
                --Sub query to get min EffectiveDate that is greater than today
            , (
                  SELECT MIN([dl1].[EffectiveDate])
                  FROM   #Deal [dl1]
                  WHERE  [dl1].[Deal_ID] = [dl].[Deal_ID]
                         AND [dl1].[EffectiveDate] > GETDATE()
              ) AS [NextEffectiveDateAfterToday]
       FROM   #Deal [dl]
```

Giving you these results:

```
Row_ID      Deal_ID              EffectiveDate Volume               PreviousRowEffectiveData NextEffectiveDateAfterToday
----------- -------------------- ------------- -------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------------
1           1479209              2018-11-01    5203                 NULL                     2019-03-01
2           1479209              2019-03-01    2727                 2018-11-01               2019-03-01
3           1479209              2019-04-01    1615                 2019-03-01               2019-03-01
4           1479209              2019-06-01    1325                 2019-04-01               2019-03-01
5           1598451              2018-12-01    2000                 NULL                     2019-04-01
6           1598451              2019-04-01    4000                 2018-12-01               2019-04-01
7           1598451              2019-08-01    4000                 2019-04-01               2019-04-01
```

Now that we have that we can use that in a sub query and then implement the business rules for DAYS if I understood correctly:

- First row for a Deal_ID, number of days from next effective date after today to today.
- If not first, number of days from previous effective date to row effective date.

Example query:

```
SELECT *
        --Case statement, if previousrow null(first record) difference in days of datday and NextEfectiveDateAfterToday
        --Else we will do the difference in days of previousrow and this rows effective date.
     , CASE WHEN [Deal].[PreviousRowEffectiveData] IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), [Deal].[NextEffectiveDateAfterToday])
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, [Deal].[PreviousRowEffectiveData], [Deal].[EffectiveDate])
       END AS [DAYS]
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                    -- LAG here partioned by the Deal_ID, we'l return NULL if first record.
                , LAG([dl].[EffectiveDate], 1, NULL) OVER ( PARTITION BY [dl].[Deal_ID]
                                                            ORDER BY [dl].[EffectiveDate]
                                                          ) AS [PreviousRowEffectiveData]
                    --Sub query to get min EffectiveDate that is greater than today
                , (
                      SELECT MIN([dl1].[EffectiveDate])
                      FROM   #Deal [dl1]
                      WHERE  [dl1].[Deal_ID] = [dl].[Deal_ID]
                             AND [dl1].[EffectiveDate] > GETDATE()
                  ) AS [NextEffectiveDateAfterToday]
           FROM   #Deal [dl]
       ) AS [Deal];
```

Giving us the final results of:

```
Row_ID      Deal_ID              EffectiveDate Volume               PreviousRowEffectiveData NextEffectiveDateAfterToday DAYS
----------- -------------------- ------------- -------------------- ------------------------ --------------------------- -----------
1           1479209              2018-11-01    5203                 NULL                     2019-03-01                  14
2           1479209              2019-03-01    2727                 2018-11-01               2019-03-01                  120
3           1479209              2019-04-01    1615                 2019-03-01               2019-03-01                  31
4           1479209              2019-06-01    1325                 2019-04-01               2019-03-01                  61
5           1598451              2018-12-01    2000                 NULL                     2019-04-01                  45
6           1598451              2019-04-01    4000                 2018-12-01               2019-04-01                  121
7           1598451              2019-08-01    4000                 2019-04-01               2019-04-01                  122
```